# how does @EnableAutoConfiguration import beans from dependent libraries which has different classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Even without using @ComponentScan, how does @EnableAutoConfiguration import beans from dependent libraries which has different classpath ?

Comment: There are special files needed for auto configuration which include all the auto configuration classes to load. Those files are in a default location with a default name.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum  what are those special files and what is the default location. please share more details and reference

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.understanding-auto-configured-beans for the explanation on how auto configuration works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How [auto-configuration works](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.understanding-auto-configured-beans) is explained in the reference guide

> Classes that implement auto-configuration are annotated with `@AutoConfiguration`. This annotation itself is meta-annotated with `@Configuration`, making auto-configurations standard `@Configuration` classes. Additional `@Conditional` annotations are used to constrain when the auto-configuration should apply. Usually, auto-configuration classes use `@ConditionalOnClass` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotations. This ensures that auto-configuration applies only when relevant classes are found and when you have not declared your own `@Configuration`.
>
> You can browse the source code of [`spring-boot-autoconfigure`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v3.2.2/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure) to see the `@AutoConfiguration` classes that Spring provides (see the [`META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v3.2.2/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports) file).

The file will list the classes to load. The one below is the `AutoConfiguration.imports` file for Spring Boot auto-configuration.

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.LifecycleAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.couchbase.CouchbaseAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.dao.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraReactiveDataAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseReactiveDataAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jdbc.JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.ldap.LdapRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jReactiveDataAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.r2dbc.R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.r2dbc.R2dbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClientAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ReactiveElasticsearchClientAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.GraphQlAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.data.GraphQlReactiveQueryByExampleAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.data.GraphQlReactiveQuerydslAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.data.GraphQlQueryByExampleAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.data.GraphQlQuerydslAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.reactive.GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.rsocket.GraphQlRSocketAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.rsocket.RSocketGraphQlClientAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.security.GraphQlWebFluxSecurityAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.security.GraphQlWebMvcSecurityAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.servlet.GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastJpaDependencyAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.influx.InfluxDbAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcClientAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.embedded.EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.LdapAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderValidatorAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.neo4j.Neo4jAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.netty.NettyAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.pulsar.PulsarAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.pulsar.PulsarReactiveAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.R2dbcAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.R2dbcTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.reactor.ReactorAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.rsocket.RSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.rsocket.RSocketRequesterAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.rsocket.RSocketServerAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.rsocket.RSocketStrategiesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.rsocket.RSocketSecurityAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.saml2.Saml2RelyingPartyAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sendgrid.SendGridAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.server.servlet.OAuth2AuthorizationServerAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.server.servlet.OAuth2AuthorizationServerJwtAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizationAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestClientAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.HttpHandlerAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.ReactiveMultipartAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.ReactiveWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebSessionIdResolverAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.function.client.ClientHttpConnectorAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MultipartAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.reactive.WebSocketReactiveAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.client.WebServiceTemplateAutoConfiguration
```